# how to compile package using command line

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am very new to Delphi. I try to compile one of the packages in my project using command line and I am getting the following error

```
dxmdaset.pas Fatal:F1026 File not found: CompatLib_DXE.dcp
```

I use the following batch files

**BuildAll.bat**

```
call rsvars.bat     
set COMPILER=%BDS%\bin\DCC32.EXE
echo Compiler: %COMPILER%
echo.
MD "%CURRENT_DIR%\..\bin"
MD "%CURRENT_DIR%\..\bin\bpl"
MD "%CURRENT_DIR%\..\bin\dcu"
cd %CURRENT_DIR%\..\bin\bpl
del *.bpl /q
del *.dcp /q
del *.drc /q
del *.map /q
cd %CURRENT_DIR%\%VCLFOLDER%\RemObjects SDK
del wo3p_03_DXE.* /s/q

:Build_CompatLib
echo ...Building CompatLib...
echo.
cd %CURRENT_DIR%\%VCLFOLDER%
call BuildCompatLib.bat

:Build_DevExpress_Old
echo ...Building DevExpress...
echo.
cd %CURRENT_DIR%\%VCLFOLDER%
call BuildDevExpress.bat old
```

**BuildCompatLib.bat**

```
@echo off
if "%COMPILER%" == "" goto no_compiler
echo Building ComaptLib Component Library:
set COMPILER_OPTIONS=%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
set COMAPTLIB_ROOT=%CD%\Compatibility
if not "%2" == "" echo You specified these dcc32 options: %COMPILER_OPTIONS%
if     "%2" == "" echo Recreating all DCUs then linking td32 info and writing a detailed 
map file.

if     "%2" == "" set COMPILER_OPTIONS=-q -b -gd -v
echo.
:CompatLib
cd %COMAPTLIB_ROOT%
echo Compiling CompatLib_DXE %COMPILER_OPTIONS%
echo.
     "%COMPILER%" CompatLib_DXE.dpk %COMPILER_OPTIONS%

if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
echo.
:end_ComaptLib
echo no errors in building CompatLib packages
echo.
echo.
goto end
:error
echo.
echo ERROR! building CompatLib packages: %~f0
echo.
pause
:end
```

**BuildDevExpress.bat**

```
@echo off
rem Compiler defined in calling batch file
if "%COMPILER%" == "" goto no_compiler
echo Building DevExpress Component Libraries:
set COMPILER_OPTIONS=%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
set DEVEXPRESS_ROOT=%CD%
if not "%2" == "" echo You specified these dcc32 options: %COMPILER_OPTIONS%
if     "%2" == "" echo Recreating all DCUs then linking td32 info and writing a detailed map file.
if     "%2" == "" set COMPILER_OPTIONS=-q -b -gd -v
echo.
:DevExpressCommon
:DevExpressMemData
set PKG_LOCATION=DevExpress\ExpressMemData\Delphi 7\Sources
rem set PKG_LOCATION=DevExpress New\ExpressMemData\Packages
cd %DEVEXPRESS_ROOT%\%PKG_LOCATION%
echo Compiling dxmds_DXE.dpk %COMPILER_OPTIONS%
echo.
     "%COMPILER%" dxmds_DXE.dpk %COMPILER_OPTIONS%
echo Compiling dcldxmds_DXE.dpk %COMPILER_OPTIONS%
echo.
     "%COMPILER%" dcldxmds_DXE.dpk %COMPILER_OPTIONS%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
cd %DEVEXPRESS_ROOT%
echo.
```

I got an error while compiling `dcldxdms_dxe.dpk`. It is actually looking for `compatlib_dxe.dcp` which was compiled earlier but couldn't find it.

Comment: can you update with a bigger picture please?

Comment: Please preview your questions before posting them. If you had done so with this one, you would have seen that the image was just wasted space in your question, and you could have cropped it somewhat so that it was at least useful). :-) Also, if you're finding that `CompatLib_DEX.dcp` and it's `.dcu` files in your `Delphi 7\Bin` folder, you've installed the components badly - they should not be anywhere near your Delphi installation directory.

Comment: @KenWhite: Sorry about the image. The CompatLib_DEX.dcp is not in my dephi7\bin folder it is in my D:\Bin and i have updated my question with the command line switches i use

Comment: @Jeeva: My answer explains what's wrong with the command line switches. Not sure why you would install third-party components in a folder named `\Bin`, but I guess it makes sense to you. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite : I updated the question with the actual batch file

Comment: Download Jedi Code Library. They had the installer that arranges all necessary DCC settings to compile their packages. Then you can either re0use that installer to build our packages or learn fro mit how to make the environment for packages compilations.

Comment: Your question keeps changing too radically to try and answer it. If you look at the edit history, it's gone from "How do I compile my package from the command line?" with just a few lines of text and a bad image to now being "How do I compile a third-party vendor's complex packages from the command line using a whole series of batch files that call each other that I didn't write, don't understand, and can't explain?" It's hard to hit a constantly moving target, and radical changes make attempts to do so look idiotic. You should contact vendor support for issues with compiling their stuff. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: I appologize for these edits. I tried to break the problem into smaller piece so that it is easy to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either

- include the proper command line switches and the paths to the compiler command line, or
- provide a DCC32.CFG file in your project folder that supplies them.

To find the switches the compiler needs, just run `dcc32` with no parameters (or with `/?` or `--help`) from the command line:

```
c:\Users\YourName>dcc32
```

or see the Delphi help file topic for `DCC32.CFG` (search the help for that exactly, without the quotes):

> You can set up a list of options in a configuration file called DCC32.CFG, which will then be used in addition to the options entered on the command line. Each line in configuration file corresponds to an extra command-line argument inserted before the actual command-line arguments. Thus, by creating a configuration file, you can change the default setting of any command-line option.
>
> The command-line compiler lets you enter the same command-line option several times, ignoring all but the last occurrence. This way, even though you've changed some settings with a configuration file, you can still override them on the command line.
>
> When dcc32 starts, it looks for DCC32.CFG in the current directory. If the file isn't found there, dcc32 looks in the directory where DCC32.EXE resides.
>
> Here's an example DCC32.CFG file, defining some default directories for include, object, and unit files, and changing the default states of the $O and $R compiler directives:

```
-IC:\DELPHI\INC;C:\DELPHI\SRC

-OC:\DELPHI\ASM
-UC:\DELPHI\UNITS
-$R+

-$O-
```

> Now, if you type:
>
> dcc32 MYSTUFF
>
> the compiler performs as if you had typed the following:

```
dcc32 -IC:\DELPHI\INC;C:\DELPHI\SRC -OC:\DELPHI\ASM -UC:\DELPHI\UNITS -$R+ -$O- MYSTUFF
```

Answer (score 0):

When compiling from the IDE, Delphi will add both the library path from the project settings as well as Delphi's own library path.

If you compile from the command line, you need to add all of those as arguments to the compiler.

There's also an option to see the line that Delphi sent to the compiler when called from the IDE, but I don't recall when they added that, so it might not be available in Delphi 7.

Comment: The option to see the compiler command line in the IDE was added in D2006, IIRC. It definitely wasn't available in D7; it was added when the change was made to use MSBuild for command-line builds.